# Java. Нужна помощь в рефакторинге дублирования кода

Tags: java, generics

У меня небольшая программа.

```
interface Store<T extends Base> {
    void add(T t);
    Simple<T> getStore();
    boolean delete(T t);
    boolean update(T oldObj, T newObj);
}

class UserStore implements Store<User> {
    private Simple<User> users = new SimpleArray<>();

    @Override
    public void add(User user) {
        users.add(user);
    }

    public Simple<User> getStore() {
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(User user) {
        for (int i = 0; i < users.getSize(); i++) {
            if (user.getId().equals(users.get(i).getId())) {
                users.delete(i);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(User oldObj, User newObj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < users.getSize(); i++) {
            if (oldObj.getId().equals(users.get(i).getId())) {
                users.update(i, newObj);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

class RoleStore implements Store<Role> {
    private Simple<Role> roles = new SimpleArray<>();

    @Override
    public void add(Role role) {
        roles.add(role);
    }

    public Simple<Role> getStore() {
        return roles;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(Role user) {
        for (int i = 0; i < roles.getSize(); i++) {
            if (user.getId().equals(roles.get(i).getId())) {
                roles.delete(i);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean update(Role oldObj, Role newObj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < roles.getSize(); i++) {
            if (oldObj.getId().equals(roles.get(i).getId())) {
                roles.update(i, newObj);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

И сам контент для сторов:
public abstract class Base {
    private final String id;

    Base(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}

public class Role extends Base {
    public Role(String id) {
        super(id);
    }
}

public class User extends Base {
    public User(String id) {
        super(id);
    }
}
```

Проблема в том что в классах `UserStore` и `RoleStore` много дублированного кода я хочу от него избавиться при помощи дженериков, но не как не получается. Но главное я хочу сделать это так что-бы у меня остался интерфейс `interface Store<T extends Base>`. Но написать `abstract class UserStore implements Store<T extends Base> {}` я не могу. А хочется сделать общий класс который вместо конкретных реализаций `User` и `Role` использует `<T extends Base>` и мог работать со всеми. Получить гибкое апи и не дублировать код но не получается. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Сделайте дефолтную реализацию в интерфейсе

Comment: Не получается у меня переменная users на полях в методах используется. А в интерфейсе ее можно только статическую сделать а это не то... хотя идея интересная...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно создать абстрактный класс с дженириком и частичной имплементацией:

```
public interface Base;
public class User implements Base {};
public class Role implements Base {};

public abstract class GenericStore <T extends Base> implements Store <T> 
{
    private Simple <T> items = new Simple <T> ();

    public void add(T item) 
    {
        items.add(item);
    }
}
```

И потом создавать его а-ля:

```
Store<User> UserStore = new GenericStore<User>():
UserStore.add(new User());
```

Так вам не надо унаследовать от Store если не хотите дублировать код операций, но всё-таки придётся если некоторые будут иметь собственную, отличную от абстрактного класса функционал.

Comment: Да! Я тоже так считаю! Но у меня в задании декларативно  задана сигнатура этого интерфейса ну и его наличие тут. А так я с вами на все 200% согласен.

Comment: Ну а в чем тогда дело? Поменяйте название моего класса на GenericStore, унаследуйте его от Store и создавайте его наподобие так: Store<User> UsersStore = new GenericStore<User>(); Паттерн Фабрики в чистом виде.

Comment: Проблема с дженериками я не могу написать public abstract class GenericStore implements Store<T extands Base> {
} и использовать Т, он заставляет меня написать либо Store<User> либо Store<Role>

Comment: Если User и Role extendят от Base то не вижу почему так и не поступить. Тогда написать можно и так: public abstract class GenericStore<T extends Base> implements Store<T>. Пример ответа в http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893481/generics-inheriting-from-an-abstract-class-that-implements-an-interface